# Match description with giving code word

Tags: mysql

Need help with this query, cannot get it work right

```
SELECT  a.code, a.description, a.adjustment FROM activity AS a 
WHERE a.pid = $customer_id AND a.consult = $consultation_id AND a.code LIKE $code
```

$code equals can be a something like this "12043 OFFICE CONSULT' (of course different numbers for different descriptions) OR 'DE-POSIT' OR 'UNKNOWN'

the problem is that DBs store this like "12043 OFF" OR UNKNOWN. My query only matches the unknown but not the ones with the number. It can match a number if I do

a.code REGEXP '^[0-9]+'  but matches any number not exact match.

If there are multiple lines with different numbers it puts the first match on all the lines

Comment: Beware [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

try using `LIKE CONCAT('%', $code ,'%')`

```
SELECT  a.code, a.description, a.adjustment FROM activity AS a 
WHERE a.pid = $customer_id AND a.consult = $consultation_id AND a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', $code ,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try ,  `LIKE '%$code%'` it fetches the record it contains the code value.

```
"SELECT  a.code, a.description, a.adjustment FROM activity AS a
WHERE a.pid = $customer_id AND a.consult = $consultation_id AND a.code LIKE '%$code%'";
```

Ref: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm

Comment: like this '%'.$code.'%' it gives me a syntax error .... Changed it to '%$code%' returns only the unknown....it returns nothing for the matching number plus description

Comment: this is the code value passed to the query ... "88203 OFFICE CONSULTATION 30 MINUT" ... DB stores a.code as "88203 OFF"

Comment: if you passed like this, it checks description contains this text `88203 OFFICE CONSULTATION 30 MINUT`, if you pass like '%88203%' in query, it will return all the result which contains the text `88203`

Comment: Oops, thanks! I will try to preg_match the passing code value then put it in query.